# PtrSafe Attribute Error MS Access

Tags: forms, vba, ms-access

I am trying to enter records into an MS Access form and am getting the following compile error:

"The code in this project must be updated for use on 64-bit systems. Please review and update Declare statements and then mark them with the PtrSafe attribute."

The code in the database is the following:

```
Private Sub cboProjectID_Change()
    Dim VarComboKey As Integer

    VarComboKey = Me.cboProjectID.Value

    Me!cboErrCod1.RowSource = "SELECT DISTINCT [Error_Reason_Code], [Reason_Code_Desc] FROM [HDR_ErrCodes] WHERE [project_ID] = " & VarComboKey
    Me!cboErrCod2.RowSource = "SELECT DISTINCT [Error_Reason_Code], [Reason_Code_Desc] FROM [HDR_ErrCodes] WHERE [project_ID] = " & VarComboKey
    Me!cboErrCod3.RowSource = "SELECT DISTINCT [Error_Reason_Code], [Reason_Code_Desc] FROM [HDR_ErrCodes] WHERE [project_ID] = " & VarComboKey
    Me!cboErrCod4.RowSource = "SELECT DISTINCT [Error_Reason_Code], [Reason_Code_Desc] FROM [HDR_ErrCodes] WHERE [project_ID] = " & VarComboKey
    Me!cboErrCod5.RowSource = "SELECT DISTINCT [Error_Reason_Code], [Reason_Code_Desc] FROM [HDR_ErrCodes] WHERE [project_ID] = " & VarComboKey
End Sub

Private Sub Form_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)


   Dim ctl As Control

   On Error GoTo Err_BeforeUpdate


   If Me.Dirty Then

      If MsgBox("Do you want to save?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, _
              "Save Record") = vbNo Then
         Me.Undo
      End If
   End If

Exit_BeforeUpdate:
   Exit Sub

Err_BeforeUpdate:
   MsgBox Err.Number & " " & Err.Description
   Resume Exit_BeforeUpdate
End Sub
```

Can someone help me update the code in order to prevent this error from popping up?

Comment: This is not all code. You have `Declare`s somewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a bit of searching i found where my declare statements were. This code fixed it:

```
  #If VBA7 Then
       Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetTickCount Lib "kernel32" () As Long
       #Else
       Private Declare Function GetTickCount Lib "kernel32" () As Long
       #End If
```